# Is there a term to describe changing a column into multiple columns in data processing?

Tags: database, data-processing

For example, say I take this table:

```
+--------+--------+
| Value1 | Value2 |
+--------+--------+
|      1 | A      |
|      2 | B      |
|      3 | A      |
|      4 | C      |
|      5 | A      |
+--------+--------+
```

And instead present it like so:

```
+--------+---+---+---+
| Value1 | A | B | C |
+--------+---+---+---+
|      1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
|      2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
|      3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
|      4 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
|      5 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
+--------+---+---+---+
```

Is there a word or a term for this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process when you take data from multiple rows with the attributes of the same object and convert them into a single row with columns corresponding to these attributes is called [data pivoting](https://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot) or data transposing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this seems to be the normalized design(First Normal Form) of the database design. Imagine if Value1 rows may have not only one of the A,B,C but A and B and C, for example. This will not satisfy the first normal form of the database as values in each column must be atomic. So, making changes to get the second table will solve the first normal form problem and also data redundancy in DBMS.
In the opposite case, which is to change the second table into multiple tables, it is called decomposition. It replaces the relation with a lot of smaller relations by breaking the table into multiple tables. The decomposition may be of two types which are as follows:

- Lossless decomposition: if it is lossless then if you do natural join
  on all the decomposition, you will get the original relation.
- Dependency preserving: this is an important constraint in DBMS and
  when decomposition is dependency preserving then at least one of the
  decomposed tables should satisfy every dependency.

You can find decomposition examples here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-base-dependency-preserving-decomposition/

I hope I could help you with my shared knowledge.

Comment: The asker did not say that he would have all values A,B,C in the same row. He could have three rows, one per each value. This is absolutely not a violation of 1NF.

Comment: You are right, but which sentence states in my answer that it is violation?

Comment: _if Value1 rows may have not only one of the A,B,C but A and B and C, for example. This will not satisfy the first normal form of the database as values in each column must be atomic_.

Comment: I just noted a case. There is uncertainty in question I think, that is why my answer is a bit general.